# Why am I not able to pass data from the parent to child component in vue using RouterView?

Tags: axios, vuejs3, vue-router

It's a simple program where I send the user-entered data to server (via axios) from home page, get the response and emit the data to App.vue. App.vue recieves the data and passes the data to all it's child components as a property. But the issue is that the data which should be sent through App.vue is not received by the child component or the binding of property is not done correctly.

**main.js**

```
createApp(App)
.use(VueRouter.createRouter({
    history: VueRouter.createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/home',
            component: Home
        },
        {
            path: '/',
            redirect: '/home'
        },
        {
            path: '/selectOne',
            component: SelectionPage,
            props: true
        }
    ]
}))
.mount('#app')
```

**home.vue** (where data is entered)

```
<template>
<RouterLink to="/selectOne">
                <button type="submit" @click="submit" style="margin-top: 1rem;"> Enter</button>
 </RouterLink>
 </template>

export default {
        // eslint-disable-next-line vue/multi-word-component-names
        name: 'Home',
        data() {
            return {
                fullInfo: {
                    name: '',
                    gender: '',
                    birthdate: '',
                    birthTime: '',
                    place: ''
                },

                table: null
            }
        },
        methods: {
            async submit() {
                let response = await axios.post('/api/selectOne', {
                        info: this.fullInfo,
                });
                let tableData = response.data;
                this.table = tableData;
                console.log(this.table);
                this.$emit('recieveData', tableData);
            }
        }
 }
```

**App.vue**

```
<template> 
  <RouterView @recieveData="dataRecieved($event)" :data="data"></RouterView>
</template>

export default {

  name: 'App',

  data() {
    return {
      data: {},
    }
  },
  methods: {
    dataRecieved(e) {
      console.log(e);
      this.data = e;
    }
  }

}
```

**SelectionPage.vue** (where data is not getting recieved)

```
<template>
    <div>

       <h1> hello {{ data }}</h1>
    </div>
</template>

export default {
    name: 'SelectionPage',
    props: ['data'],
  }
```

the server sends the response properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a possible race condition.  I would not wrap the home.vue button in `<RouterLink>`.  Clicking the button is calling the submit method and performing routing *at the same time*.  Try a more synchronous approach:

```html
<template>
  <button type="submit" @click="submit" style="margin-top: 1rem">Enter</button>
</template>
```

```js
async submit() {
  let response = await axios.get('/api/selectOne', {
    info: this.fullInfo,
  });
  let tableData = response.data;
  this.table = tableData;
  console.log(this.table);
  this.$emit("recieveData", tableData);
  this.$router.push("/selectOne");  // <-- push AFTER emit
},
```

Comment: I later realized in other part of the app that it renders the page before the data was actually available to display